# Problem passing parameters in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, controllers

I have the following controller:

public ActionResult Search(string Name, int? Friend, int? Page)

It works if I use this url localhost/users/search/name but these don't localhost/users/search/name/1 and localhost/users/search/name/1/1

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  You don't get the right parameter values, or the method is never called?  Either way, it would help if you showed how you're mapping your routes.

Comment: I have no custom routes set up, when I add the additional parameters I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define additional route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "UsersSearch",                                              // Route name
                "users/search/{name}/{friend}/{page}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Search" }  // Parameter defaults
            );


routes.MapRoute(
                "UsersSearch",                                              // Route name
                "users/search/{name}/{friend}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Search" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: So by default it accepts one parameter, and if you want additional parameters you have to map them specifically?